# http client for OAuth endpoint

Tags: javascript, oauth, gitlab

I'm trying to get an OAuth access token from the GitLab CE endpoint for OAuth. I've got the code parameter fine in JS, but when I make an Ajax request to the access token page, it throws an error about the server not being CORS enabled, and the origin null not being allowed. Why is my origin null? I also looked at the gitlab documentation, it says you have to use a http client, and then it shows an example of `RestClient`. What is this? I've tried using it but it doesn't work. Please see below for my code:

```
if (getQueryVariable('code') === false) {
            if (local !== false) {
                window.location.replace('https://gitlab.com/oauth/authorize?client_id=####&redirect_uri=http://localhost:4000&response_type=code');
            } else { //live
                window.location.replace('https://gitlab.com/oauth/authorize?client_id=####&redirect_uri=http://roconnor.gitlab.io/repoViewer&response_type=code');
            }

        } else {

            var oauthcode;

            if (local !== false) {
                oauthcode = $.getJSON('http://gitlab.com/oauth/token?client_id=####&client_secret=####&code=' + getQueryVariable('code') + '&grant_type=AUTHORIZATION_CODE&redirect_uri=http://localhost:4000');

                var parameters = 'client_id=####&client_secret=####&code=' + getQueryVariable('code') + '&grant_type=AUTHORIZATION_CODE&redirect_uri=http://localhost:4000'
                RestClient.post 'http://gitlab.com/oauth/token', parameters //this is the code given by the docs
            } else {
                oauthcode = $.getJSON('http://gitlab.com/oauth/token?client_id=####&client_secret=####&code=' + getQueryVariable('code') + '&grant_type=AUTHORIZATION_CODE&redirect_uri=http://roconnor.gitlab.io/repoViewer');
            }


            console.log(oauthcode); //the error gets thrown here
```